# Receive .vcf file from Files app in Nougat and Oreo versions to my app

Tags: android, share, android-permissions, android-version

I've an Android App, which works fine in Jelly Bean and Kitkat versions. The app will receive .vcf file as `Intent` from **File Manager** app using **Complete Action Using** option.

Now in Android Nougat and Oreo versions, Using **Files** app, there is an option **Open with** or **Share** will not list my App.

How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomOrange"
        >
        <activity>
        ...
        ...
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ViewContactActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_vcf" >

            <intent-filter> <!-- Handle http https requests without mimeTypes: -->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.vcf" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter> <!-- Handle with mimeTypes, where the suffix is irrelevant: -->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter> <!-- Handle intent from a file browser app: -->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT_OR_EDIT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**ViewContactActivity.java**

```
public  class       ViewContactActivity
        extends     AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = ViewContactActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String  VIEW_CONTACT_BY_ID      = "viewContactById";

    private static final int    MODE_VIEW_BY_ID     = 0;
    private static final int    MODE_VIEW_BY_FILE   = 1;
    private int                 viewContactMode;

    private ActionBar mActionBar;
    ContactDetails contactDetails;
    String mFilePath;
    private GroupInfoPickerAlertDialog mGroupInfoPickerAD;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vcf);


        contactDetails = new ContactDetails(this);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Long id = intent.getLongExtra(VIEW_CONTACT_BY_ID, -1L);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (id != -1L) {
            viewContactMode = MODE_VIEW_BY_ID;
            contactDetails.collectContactDetail(id);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new BufferedInputStream(contactDetails.getDisplayPhoto()));
        } else {
            viewContactMode = MODE_VIEW_BY_FILE;
            Uri fileUri = intent.getData();
            mFilePath = fileUri.getPath();
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() - file path: " + mFilePath);
            //onCreate() - file path: /path/to/file.vcf

            contactDetails.readVCard2_1(fileUri);
        }


        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        if(mActionBar == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() mActionBar == null");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() mActionBar != null");
        }
        mActionBar.setCustomView(null);
        mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);


        contactDetails.displayContact(bitmap);
        if (viewContactMode == MODE_VIEW_BY_FILE) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_text_view);
            textView.setText(mFilePath);// + "\n\n" + stringBuilder);
        } else {
            View v = (View) findViewById(R.id.message_text_view).getParent();
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // ....
    // ....
    // Other codes...
    // ....
    // ....

}
```

Comment: There is no "Files" app in standard Android. You would need to contact the developers of that "Files" app and ask them. Or, edit your question and post the `<activity>` element (and its `<intent-filter>` children), and perhaps we can suggest some improvements to help with compatibility.

Comment: @CommonsWare Question updated with code

Comment: @CommonsWare I saw "Files" app in Android Emulation for accessing files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<intent-filter>` elements support `http`, `https`, and `file`. Few "file manager" apps will use any of those on Android 7.0+, in part because the `file` scheme is banned.

Replace:

```
        <intent-filter> <!-- Handle intent from a file browser app: -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT_OR_EDIT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
        </intent-filter>
```

with:

```
        <intent-filter> <!-- Handle intent from a file browser app: -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT_OR_EDIT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Then, make sure that `readVCard2_1()` handles `file` and `content` `Uri` schemes, such as by calling `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to access the stream.

Comment: How to get the real file path from content uri ? Most solutions seen in stackoverflow.com are related to Camera related App. So I'm bit confused.

Comment: @ChrisJ: "How to get the real file path from content uri ?" -- there is no "real file path". Call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to access the stream, passing in the `Uri`.

Comment: I would like to show the Path where the file is located, when the file is opened in an Android Activity